# Select papers having three or more authors

Tags: sql

I have two tables author and paper. How do I find the paper which has three or more authors? I tried using

`select distinct acnum,panum from author Where acnum >3 order by acnum;`

and

`select p.panum,p.title from paper p Join author a on a.panum = p.panum Group by p.panum,p.title Having count(a.acnum) >3;`

am I doing it wrong?
The relation between the author and paper is the paper number.

Comment: what dbms ? mysql, sql server or something else ??

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, You ask if you are doing it wrong, but havn't provided what you have tried, or the schema you are using.

We need more details in order to help.

Comment: show me your current table structure

Comment: @RyanTheLeach i tried using this 
select acnum,panum
from author
Where acnum >3
order by acnum;

Comment: "I tried using join"   What kind of join?  Inner Join?  Left Join?  You replied to the comments and didn't even reveal the join.  Be consistent in your question and responses if you expect help.  You may want to look at other posts on Stack Overflow as an example for how to ask a question here.

Comment: @zorkolot this is what i usedselect p.panum,p.title
from paper p
Join author a on
a.panum = p.panum
Group by p.panum,p.title
Having count(a.acnum) >3;

Comment: will see other posts as an example my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said in the comments:

```
 i used select p.panum,p.title from paper p Join author a on a.panum = p.panum Group by p.panum,p.title Having count(a.acnum) >3
```

Lets assume that's the exact query you used.  You did not do a `COUNT` in the select, but use `HAVING`.  `HAVING` analyzes the aggregation that should be in the select, but there is none.  You just need to put a `COUNT` in the select:

```
SELECT p.panum
      ,p.title
      ,COUNT(*) as "thecount"
  FROM paper P INNER JOIN author a ON a.pnum = p.panum
GROUP BY p.panum
        ,p.title
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

Comment: No, it needs to use the aggregate as written.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify better your fields and tables in the question, but in general you have to do a group by author and set a condition with having count. Something like

```
SELECT * FROM paper JOIN author ON author ....
GROUP BY author
HAVING COUNT(*) > 3
```

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: It will depend on your table structure / schema whether this will even work, we really need more details, including whether author -> paper is a many to many, one to many, many to one, or one to one relationship.

Comment: > 3 should probably be >= 3